# Calling `odbc` connection within function does not display in RStudio Connection Pane

Tags: r, odbc, rstudio

I'm working to streamline some database connections.  Using the `odbc` package, I have successfully established a connection with one of my databases like so:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "db_name", 
                 UID = "username",
                 PWD = "password")
```

This works, and the database schema displays in the Connection Pane as anticipated (using `RStudio Server 1.1.383`)

However, I need to call this connection within a user-defined function that decrypts our users credentials.  A minimal example:

```
db_Connect_mod <- function(userid,
                           password,
                           ...){

  # Needed Processes, but ommitted for simplicity of this question
  # ...

  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "db_name", 
                   UID = userid,
                   PWD = password)
  return(con)
}
```

So then I run:

```
con <- db_Connect_mod(userid, password, ...)
```

The actual database connection `con` is successful, but it no longer appears in the RStudio Connection Pane.

I know that `odbc` uses a [Connections Contract](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/connections-contract.html), but it doesn't seem that it carries over to my new function.  Is there a way to force the Connections Contract to carry over to the top-level function?

I have looked at using `odbc:::on_connection_opened(con, code = "...")`, which seems to work, but is not as functional as inheriting the Connections Contract from `odbc` within my new function and would rather not be reliant on a non-exported function.

I believe this behavior is due to changes from [this odbc github issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/122)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Didn't seem to be much interest, but posting the work-around I've been using:

I am using `match.call()` to gather the arguments, and then parsing that into the `odbc:::on_connection_opened()` function as previously discussed.  Probably not best practices, but hey it works.

I added the logical argument `connection_pane` to easily turn off or on this feature:

```
internal_package::db_Connect_mod <- function(userid,
                           password,
                           connection_pane,
                           ...){

  # Needed Processes, but ommitted for simplicity of this question
  # ...

  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "db_name", 
                   UID = userid,
                   PWD = password)

  if(connection_pane){    
    code <- c(match.call())   # This saves what was typed into R

    odbc:::on_connection_opened(
      con,                                
      paste(c("library(internal_package)",                                        
              paste("con <-", gsub(", ", ",\n\t", code))),
            collapse = "\n"))  
  }
  return(con)
}
```

Imagine this could look a lot prettier with `glue` or `stringr` for further improvements

Comment: I think this issue is also related to the question/answer here https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/158 and this should also fix the issue https://community.rstudio.com/t/db-connection-through-dbi-is-too-slow-for-large-db/5550/5

Comment: Nice! I was trying to do the same with `rstudioapi::sendToConsole()`, but this is much cleaner.